# Bootstrap4 align payment buttons in two rows and three rows in mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 9 payment buttons. I want to align 5 buttons in the first row and the rest 4 buttons in the second row below first one. But in mobile phone, I'd like to show 9 buttons in 3 x 3 style. I am using Bootstrap 4. My current html is as follows. How can I do this?

```
<div class="payment-btns mt-4">
    <div class="row mx-auto">
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/PayPal.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/VISA.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/giropay.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/SOFORT.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/Belfius.png" ></a>

       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/KBC.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/CBC.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/iDEAL.png" ></a>
       <a class="col" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/Bancontact.png" ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your custom classes??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Nothing special in custom class `payment-btns`. Just for jQuery. You can ignore custom classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make it without bootstrap 4,

```css
.button-div{
 width: 20%;
}
@media (max-width: 575px){
 .button-div{
 width: calc(100% / 3);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-btns mt-4">
    <div class="row mx-auto justify-content-center">
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/PayPal.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/VISA.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/giropay.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/SOFORT.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/Belfius.png" ></a>

       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/KBC.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/CBC.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/iDEAL.png" ></a>
       <a class="button-div" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="./assets/img/payment/Bancontact.png" ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

only using html and css:

Comment: You're right. Bootstrap cannot solve all problem. Sometimes we should use our custom classes and styles. One thing to add: <div class="row mx-auto justify-content-center">. Reflect changes and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <mn class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
        </mn>
        <mno class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
            <pp class="col-4">
                <m class="btn btn-primary">ABCDEFG</m>
            </pp>
        </mno>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

check this: https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/78uksz1j/1/

try to read some documentation aboout botstarp4 grid  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/
and css's flexbox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

they are two different things

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want 5-4 and 3x3 style only. Is that possible?

Comment: not using bootsrap4 because ` class=col-12` will divide first first three buttons in first row itself and the how can you shift it to two buttons  from other row up there . Youw ill have to use custom html  css fro it . I am trying for it that will be lengthy.

Comment: I heard somewhere that some bootstrap class will break line according to viewport size. I think it's related to display:flex. What do you think?

Comment: in display : flex you willl have to give flex direction in that each button will be shifted in rows or columns but not as 5-4 and 3x3 rows !!!